# Get counts of co-occurences from a database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I calculate the number of times a pair of "tags" occurs together?

In this example, I have 3 StackOverflow questions and their tags in a table. I want to get the number of times tags exist together on the same question.

```
Question ID   Tag ID
--------------------------
1             1
1             2
1             3

2             1
2             2

3             1
3             4
```

Desired Result:

```
Tag 1     Tag 2    Count
---------------------------
1         2        2
1         3        1
1         4        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self join, then group by.

```
select t1.tag_id as tag1, t2.tag_id as tag2, count(*) as occurrence
from yourtable as t1
join yourtable as t2
on t1.question_id = t2.question_id
t1.tagid < t2.tagid
group by tag1, tag2;
```

Comment: Oops sorry Will, I edited the answer by mistake (tried to add the result to my answer). Anyway, left no changes.

Answer (score 1):

The following works and also avoids having tags co-occur with themselves.

```
select *, count(*) from (
   select a.tag tag1, b.tag tag2 from mytable a, mytable b 
   where a.question=b.question and a.tag < b.tag
 ) t group by tag1, tag2;

| tag1 | tag2 | count(*) |
|------|------|----------|
|    1 |    2 |        2 |
|    1 |    3 |        1 |
|    1 |    4 |        1 |
|    2 |    3 |        1 |
```

Comment: So this will return 2 identical rows for each tag pair. One with `tag1 = "javascript" and tag2 = "react"`, and a second with the tags reversed as `tag1 = "react" and tag2 = "javascript"`. I thought I'd do another self join to clean it up, but the only syntax I could think of would cause your query to be run twice. Any ideas how to deduplicate?

Comment: The situation you describe doesn't happen because of the `a.tag < b.tag` clause. Did you try running this statement?